# Failure of Ruby case equality operator ===

Tags: ruby, switch-statement, date-range, ruby-2.3

I have:

```
require 'date'

pap1 = Date.parse('1968-06-12')
pap2 = Date.parse('1968-12-31')
dat = Date.parse('1968-06-12')
dat2 = dat + 5 # => #<Date: 1968-06-17 ((2440025j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>
```

In the example below, I want to test if a date falls in a range of dates. I expect the date range `pap1..pap2` to cover `dat` and `dat2`. The `case` equality operator should count `dat` as within the range of `pap1` and `pap2`:

```
case dat
when (pap1..pap2)
  puts 'in range'
else
  puts 'not in range'
end
# >> not in range

(pap1..pap2).cover?(dat)              # => true
(pap1..pap2).include?(dat)            # => true
(pap1..pap2) === dat                  # => false
puts 'works' if (pap1..pap2) === dat  # => nil

(pap1..pap2).cover?(dat2)              # => true
(pap1..pap2).include?(dat2)            # => true
(pap1..pap2) === dat2                  # => false
puts 'works' if (pap1..pap2) === dat2  # => nil
```

But it doesn't. Am I missing something?

Comment: Cannot be reproduced.

Comment: Regardless of that, if you have pinned down that whatever is wrong with your environment is with `===`, and you know that `case` relies on `===`, then you should simply ask about `===`, not about `case`, making the question simpler.

Comment: What version of ruby are you using? This works fine for me in e.g. ruby 2.3.1

Comment: Hmm.  I get the same result on two systems.  Are you seeing `(pap1..pap2) === date` return true?  BTW, I did mention case equality operator in the question (edited to mention === explicitly) and gave the version as  2.3.0.  Thanks for giving this a try.

Comment: I'll try to install 2.3.1 and see if I get the same.

Comment: Are you testing `(pap1..pap2) === date` or `puts 'works' if (pap1..pap2) === date`? The latter should always return `nil` regardless of the condition.

Comment: @sawa, I understand.  Just included to puts to generate output.  The first is the real test, which ought to return `true`.

Comment: OK.  Just installed ruby 2.3.1 and the test passes.  A bug in 2.3.0?

Comment: @sawa, could you try this with 2.3.0?  If you get the same, I'll try to submit a bug report.  Seems like a pretty serious bug if verified.

Comment: OK.  Looks like this is a known bug.  I assume the fix will be backported at some point.  [Bug Report](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12003)

Comment: I actually do not believe you enough to spend my time testing them. What exactly is your code, and what result do you get?

Comment: @sawa What do you mean 'what is you code' and 'what result do you get'?  I included both my code and the results, via `# =>` comments in my OP.  Don't test it, it's a known bug, so the ruby maintainers believed it, thank goodness.

Comment: Okay. Well done.

Answer (score 4):

This is apparently a known bug in Ruby 2.3.0, fixed at some point in 2.3.1.  Here is the bug report [Bug Report on === with Dates](https://bugs.ruby-lang.org/issues/12003).  Answer: upgrade.

Comment: It was fixed in [this commit](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/commit/62b750bb55916e526fb53cb4c19da777872c27f6).